# Gaussian-like integral : $\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ I know this should be $\frac{1}{4 \lambda} \sqrt \frac{\pi}{\lambda}$(By checking answer to the problem) but was unable to prove it... I really need some hint on how to evaluate this integral, thanks.

Comment: Write as $x\cdot x e^{-\lambda x^2}$ and integrate by parts?

Comment: Differentiate $e^{-x^{2}}$ twice and seewhat happens!

Comment: Oh yes! I haven't thought of that! Great tip :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts taking $u =x$ and $v' = xe^{-\lambda x^2}$, we get: $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda x^2}}{2\lambda }\, dx - \frac{xe^{-\lambda x^2}}{2\lambda}\bigg \lvert_{0}^{\infty}$$ $$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda x^2}}{2\lambda}\, dx$$

Now substituting $u= \sqrt \lambda x$ should give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm dx}\newcommand{\dy}{\mathrm dy}\newcommand{\dr}{\mathrm dr}\newcommand{\dtheta}{\mathrm d\theta}$I'll start from the very beginning and show that$$I(\lambda)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\dx\, e^{-\lambda x^2}\color{red}{=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{\lambda}}}$$This can be done by first squaring the expression and using Fubini's theorem to get$$I^2(\lambda)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\dx\,\dy\,e^{-\lambda(x^2+y^2)}=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\dr\,\dtheta\,re^{-\lambda r^2}$$Where the last step is there by switching to polar coordinates. We can rewrite that as$$I^2(\lambda)=-\frac {\pi}2\frac 1{2\lambda}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\dr-2\lambda re^{-\lambda r^2}=-\frac {\pi}{4\lambda}\int\limits_1^0\mathrm dz=\frac {\pi}{4\lambda}$$with the last expression being obtained through the substitution $z=\exp(-\lambda r^2)$. Taking the square root, we see that$$I(\lambda)=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{\lambda}}$$And  differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ gives us the solution that everybody else is getting$$I'(\lambda)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\dx\, x^2e^{-\lambda x^2}\color{blue}{=\frac 1{4\lambda}\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{\lambda}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$ with respect to $-\lambda$ gives $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda^3}}$.